# How to show image in generated pdf by dompdf using symfony 4.2?

Tags: php, symfony, dompdf, symfony-4.2

[image]I am genearting a pdf file using DOMPDF. My pdf file is admit card which holds the information about the particular student.

In this admit card I have wo images to show. So in my twig file,

**Profile Image:**

```
<img src="{{ response['display_image'] }}" alt="Profile Pic" width="100px" height="100px" class="img-thumbnail" />
```

**Company Image:**

```
<img src="images/webkul.png" alt="Webkul"/>
```

Both of these images are not generated in my PDF file. I gives '*image not found or type unknown*'.

> > I am fetching profile image from database while company image is
> >     stored in project file that is,
>
> public/assets/images/xyz.png

**Controller:**

```
$pdfOptions = new Options();

        $pdfOptions->set('defaultFont', 'Arial');
        $pdfOptions->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);
        $dompdf = new Dompdf($pdfOptions);
        $html = $this->renderView('download_pdf/index.html.twig', [
            'title' => "Admit-Card",
            'response' => $response,
            'data' => $data,
        ]);

        $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
        $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
        $dompdf->render();
```

I have attached the screen-shot.

**How should I give path in my twig file so that image can be rendered in PDF file?**

Comment: The error is pretty clear. I think the path is not correct.

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa: I know, but I am looking for solution though.

Comment: What is the full path of the image on disk?

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa: I have mentioned it in my question, it is 'public/assets/images/xyz.png'

Comment: That's not the full path, is it `student/public/assets/images/xyz.png` ?

Comment: Is `public` in the root of the project?

Comment: Can you try `<img src="public/assets/{{ response['display_image'] }}" alt="Webkul"/>`?

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa: I am using 'student' as prefix in my route.

Comment: what about the symfony twig extension {{ asset('assets/images/xyz.png') }} method ? (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#asset)

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa   <img src="public/assets/{{ response['display_image'] }}" alt="Webkul"/> did not worked, result is same.

Comment: @Elbarto: initially I have tried the same but it did not worked.

Comment: Load the view in a browser and with inspect element try to figure out the path

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa: both images are loaded correctly when I load the view on browser.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Laire: Yes. Actually problem exists in the header part of HTML file. I was extending <head> of my project which was containing lots of CSS and JS.
I simply removed the head and used a simple and clean instead and my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Actually problem exists in the header part of HTML file. I was extending *head* of my project which was containing lots of CSS and JS. I simply removed the head and used a simple and clean *head* instead and my problem was solved.**

Note:
Do not extender header/footer of your project into Html of pdf file, instead use a new one for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole path from the disk:

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1523

EX:

```
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
$options = new Options();
$options->set('isRemoteEnabled', TRUE);
$options->set('tempDir', '/home2/directory/public_html/directory/pdf-export/tmp');
$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
```